# Not getting all files when copying Users folder

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, copy-paste, file-transfer

I have a friends laptop and I took her hard drive out and put it in an external HD enclosure. I plan on wiping it so that I can reinstall windows. Problem is that when I plug the external HD to my computer and try to copy the entire Users folder to my PC (for backup purposes) I am only getting a fraction of it. The users folder is 174 gb when I view it in properties, but when I start the copy/paste procedure it says it is only moving about 2.4 gbs of it....Help!

Comment: Make sure hidden files are visable.

Comment: have you tried something like robocopy already? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

Comment: You can't do this without taking ownership of the folder and all files within it..

Comment: So why the down votes? Is this not a valid question?

Comment: Regarding "ownernship", I downloaded and executed a script that added a "take ownership" command to my right click context menu. I ran that on the folder and then tried the copy and got the same behavior.

Comment: I have not tried Robocopy yet. I will give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't some of the problem be that some of the folders are cross linked, junctions, or hard links or whatever, and windows properties and other size things still duplicate the items as if there is really 2 there, giving totally wrong size info?  1/2 the stuff in there may not be useful after reinstalling everything (not just the os) , picking the needed items and users stored items carefully might be a better choice.